# Handle mouse events on two overlapping nodes - Javafx

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, mouseevent

I am building a Java app. This app operates as a sterotypical "paint" app where you can select a color and draw on the canvas. Except... I will have an array of circles distributed on top of the canvas. I want these circles to immediately change color if, when the user is drawing and the mouse gets within X (10) pixels of the circle (where X is the width of the line drawn divided by 2).

In the following picture example, the user started drawing with RED. This is the moment the red touches the circle in which I need the circle's fill to become that red color
[image: Painting Circles]

Here's my code. I have a canvas that is part of a group. I also created a circle node and made that part of the group. I suppose I need to somehow create a mouse event that will trigger when the user is drawing near each circle. I will eventually have many circles on the canvas but I'm starting out with only 1 for testing purposes.

```
package paintingcircles;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;


public class LayerController {

    private ColorPicker colorPicker;
    private Group root;
    private Group canvasGroup;
    private Canvas canvas1;
    private GraphicsContext gc1;


    // Reference to the main application
    private MainApp mainApp;

     /**
      * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
      * 
      * @param mainApp
      */
      public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
          this.mainApp = mainApp;

          //get data from main app if necessary
      }

    public void initialize(){

        createLayers();
        handleLayers();
        createCircles();

    }

    private void createLayers(){

        canvas1 = new Canvas(400, 400);

        // Obtain Graphics Context
        gc1 = canvas1.getGraphicsContext2D();
        initDraw(gc1);

        //create root group
        Group root = new Group();

        canvasGroup = new Group(); 
        canvasGroup.getChildren().add(canvas1);


        //add nodes to the root group
        VBox vBox = new VBox(); //lays out children in a vertical box
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(colorPicker, canvasGroup);
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 425);
        mainApp.getPrimaryStage().setTitle("Painting Circles");
        mainApp.getPrimaryStage().setScene(scene);
        mainApp.getPrimaryStage().show();

    }

    private void initDraw(GraphicsContext gc){

        colorPicker = new ColorPicker();

        double canvasWidth = gc.getCanvas().getWidth();
        double canvasHeight = gc.getCanvas().getHeight();

        gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setLineWidth(10);

        gc.fill();
        gc.strokeRect(
                0,              //x of the upper left corner
                0,              //y of the upper left corner
                canvasWidth,    //width of the rectangle
                canvasHeight);  //height of the rectangle

        gc.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
        gc.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue());
        gc.setLineWidth(1);
    }

    private void handleLayers(){

           canvas1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, 
                   new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

               @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                   gc1.beginPath();
                   gc1.setLineWidth(20);
                   gc1.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                   gc1.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue());
                   gc1.strokeRoundRect(event.getX(), event.getY(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
               }
           });

           canvas1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, 
                   new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

               @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                //TODO: Smooth out the mouse_dragged drawing
                gc1.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                   gc1.setLineWidth(20);
                   gc1.setStroke(colorPicker.getValue());
                   gc1.stroke();

               }
           });

           canvas1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, 
                   new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

               @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

               }
           });

       }

    private void createCircles(){

        Circle c = new Circle();
        c.setCenterX(100.0f);
        c.setCenterY(100.0f);
        c.setRadius(25);
        c.setStrokeWidth(5);
        c.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        c.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvasGroup.getChildren().add(c);

            /*This is my attempt at creating a mouse event that will trigger when 
             *the user drags the mouse near the circle with the idea that it will
             *eventually color the circle. This didn't work...
             */
        c.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

               @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                   gc1.setLineWidth(20);
                   gc1.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
                   gc1.strokeRoundRect(event.getX(), event.getY(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
               }

           });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out... I needed to capture the "Mouse_Drag_Over" event after calling "startFullDrag()".

```
canvas1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, 
           new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

       @Override
       public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
           canvas1.startFullDrag();       
       }
   });

c.addEventHandler(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_OVER, new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>(){

       @Override
       public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
           c.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());   
       }
   });
```